# active directory authentication + authorization asp.net mvc + webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Let us say we have an asp.net mvc application that uses active directory (AD) for authentication and authorization. The views use jquery to consume restful webapi endpoints secured via AD as well. The webapi's restful endpoints may be hosted separately (e.g. not necessarily within the asp.net mvc application). Would the token created during the asp.net mvc's authentication process automatically be issued to the restful endpoints or does this have to be arranged somehow?

PS:

I have noticed that asp.net mvc can now automatically include webapi controllers. I always thought that this bad practice (i.e. to host everything in the same application).

Comment: any luck with this on newer NET technologies (e.g. NET 6)?